# Link read only excel sheet with access

Tags: excel, ms-access

We have an access database that has a table that I'd like to link with excel (and dropbox), so that the excel workbook can be viewed, searched and filtered on dropbox compatible smartphones. The only problem is that I want the excel workbooks to be read only, so that they cannot be saved. So the idea is, you can search from the product list on a spreadsheet program on your smartphone, which auto updates every time a change is made in access, but no changes can be made from the phones. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a DropBox folder does not give read only permissions, so I don't believe you would want this in a publicly accessible shared folder, but you can provide a link to the file which they then open in their spreadsheet viewer.

To do this, I would isolate the spreadsheet to its own folder though.
https://www.dropbox.com/help/60/en

Comment: Thanks for that - but to my knowledge its not possible to edit a linked excel table in access - so looks like im going to have to turn to MySQL & PHP

Comment: I must misinterpret the question as I thought you didn't want the users to be able to edit/read only.  You would still have full access to the file, either via your dropbox account or the file system with changes uploaded via dropbox.  I may need more info on the problem.